# Making a Get request in brightscript for roku channel not working

Tags: xml, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am building a Roku tv channel, I have displayed a keyboard so user can type, and there are two buttons to search, I have made an observer on these buttons, when the button is pressed, I want to make a get request to get results, but the API call is not succeeding in components/keyboard.brs which is linked with components/keyboard.xml, but this same API call succeed if I call in source/main.brs on the top.
[image: Here you can see I have made observer on buttons and then calling another function]

[image: fetchResults function which is called from searchImages and searchFeed functions on button clicked]

Can't understand this, please let me know if you know something about that, or any resource where can I find these things.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All http requests need to be performed on a [task thread](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/task.md).

You can see a working example of this on Roku's github samples repository [here](https://github.com/rokudev/samples/tree/master/ux%20components/control/TaskExample).

Here's the snippet of task code from that sample:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>

<!--********** Copyright 2016 Roku Corp.  All Rights Reserved. **********-->

<component name = "ContentReader" extends = "Task" >

  <interface>
    <field id = "contenturi" type = "uri" />
    <field id = "content" type = "node" />
  </interface>

  <script type = "text/brightscript" >

    <![CDATA[

    sub init()
      m.top.functionName = "getcontent"
    end sub

    sub getcontent()
      content = createObject("roSGNode", "ContentNode")

      contentxml = createObject("roXMLElement")

      readInternet = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
      readInternet.setUrl(m.top.contenturi)
      contentxml.parse(readInternet.GetToString())

      if contentxml.getName()="Content"
        for each item in contentxml.GetNamedElements("item")
          itemcontent = content.createChild("ContentNode")
          itemcontent.setFields(item.getAttributes())
        end for
      end if

      m.top.content = content
    end sub

    ]]>

  </script>

</component>
```

And this is how you create and start the task:

```
m.readXMLContentTask = createObject("roSGNode", "ContentReader")
m.readXMLContentTask.observeField("content", "setcontent")
m.readXMLContentTask.contenturi = "http://www.sdktestinglab.com/Tutorial/content/xmlcontent.xml"
m.readXMLContentTask.control = "RUN"
```

You can see a slightly more complex example of http requests in a task here on the RokuCommunity sample-projects repo: https://github.com/rokucommunity/sample-projects/tree/master/standard-with-task

Comment: but I have to pass argument to function which you are running here m.readXMLContentTask.control = "RUN", how can I pass some query that user have typed into this function?

Comment: `m.readXMLContentTask.control = "RUN"` is how you _start_ the task. To pass "arguments", you need to set fields on the task. That's what the `m.readXMLContentTask.contenturi = "http://www.sdktestinglab.com/Tutorial/content/xmlcontent.xml"` is doing.